# Calculating the flux over a triangle

Tags: calculus, integration, parametrization

So there is something I don't understand here, I have to calculate the flux over the triangle with vertices (1, 0, 0) , (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1).

Where \begin{equation} \vec A = (xy, yz, zx)\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
\phi = \oint_C \vec A \cdotp \,d\vec s\
= \oint_c xydx +yzdy + zxdz
= \iint_S \nabla \times\vec A \cdot dS
\end{equation}

The tranformation used is

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x = u -v\\
y = 1 - u - v\\
z = 2v
\end {cases}
\end{equation}

In my answer I used
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x = u\\
y = v\\
z = 1-u-v\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

But I end up with a different answer. I think it has to do with the way I parametrized it?

Comment: "With a different answer"...from what? What is "the answer"?

Comment: Have you borne in mind that you need to take the parameterisation’s differentials into account when you set out to calculate the integral?

Comment: @SamSkywalker no indeed I haven't

Comment: Try and tell us what comes out of that. That’s a fairly common mistake.

Comment: No I don't think I understand it.
The solution is -1/2 but I keep getting -1.

So $\nabla \times F =  (-y, -z, -x)$

I get $r_u \times r_v = (1,1,1)$

$\iint(-y,-z,-x) \cdot(1,1,1)dudv$

$-\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} dudv = -1$







The correct solution is (changed signs because of the flux)

$
\iint(y,z,x)(-2,-2,-2)dudx$

$-2 \iint dudv$

$-2 \int_{0}^{\frac12}\int_{v}^{1-v} dudx = \frac12$                      Sorry for the really bad way of presenting is, I'm trying to figure out how all of this works, I have never used Latex and such.